# Row Wrapping on Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place some columns and Rows from a To-Do List, but I want it to be in this order:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Not like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

My code, there is a button that will add a new element to the Array that will display on a new `<li>` with Vue.Js when I click it:

```
 <div class="container p-2 bg-dark text-white">
   <ul class="row">
     <li class="col-sm-3" v-for="(tarea, index) in tareas" @click="active">{{index}}-{{tarea}}</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

May you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) `order` but it won't work dynamically without js script... This is hardcoded example:

```
 <div class="container p-2 bg-dark text-white">
   <ul class="row">
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-1">1</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-4">2</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-7">3</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-2">4</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-5">5</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-8">6</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-3">7</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-6">8</li>
     <li class="col-sm-4 order-9">9</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```